# Will Deploying a code along with excel file work?

Tags: python, deployment, web-applications

I am trying to create a small application in flask.
So I will be web scraping the data from a website and updating it in a excel file which is in the path of my code files. Later I read the excel and manipulate data using pandas. So basically I am using this excel file as a mini database

My question is when I deploy the code can the excel file be retained with the current existing data it already had?

Comment: I'm no lawyer but you might want to check the fine print around deploying an Excel file  as part of an app. using Excel as a DB sounds heavy handed. Why not simply use a .csv?

Comment: yeah csv also looks fine for me. In that case can I proceed and still deploy the application without any issues? @MitchWheat

Comment: Btw that file will consist only maximum 20 rows at a time @MitchWheat

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how heavily the file will be used and if it may cause concurrency issues. Consider that if you have multiple requests coming into the Flask application that triggers multiple concurrent reads/writes to the excel / csv file, you may end up overwriting over content unintentionally.

If the information that you need to store is only 20 rows at a time like you mentioned in the comments, then consider using a lightweight db like sqlite.

Comment: What if I don't want to use sqlite and have only 20 rows. Can I use excel or csv in that case? @Trivikram Muralidharan

Comment: If you see no situation that causes a concurrency issue (i.e., where there are multiple simultaneous requests to the flask application that will result in a race condition-like scenario of multiple file writes to the csv file at the same time), then I don't see a problem with using a csv file. 

You can try this out yourself. Write a simple script to send multiple concurrent requests to your flask application and see if the csv file is being utilized correctly based on the responses you receive for each of the concurrent requests.

Comment: I am using this csv file just to read and compare data with a data from a website. So basically one request at a time. So I guess its good

Comment: It's a little strange that you say it's one request at a time. What assures you that there will be only one request coming into the app at any given time? Web apps like Flask are designed to execute incoming requests simultaneously.

Comment: Its because its an RPA application which is designed for one particular user

Comment: If the RPA application is designed to execute and process modules in a sequence before triggering the next web-scraping and csv generating module, then it should be fine. But either way, as a general improvement to your coding ability, try avoiding situations where you might run into race conditions.